# Language Specific Custom 404 page in Liferay

Tags: liferay-6.2

I know the procedure for adding the custom 404 page. What I want is to fetch user language in 404 page and show the error message in his locale.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for Posting the question but the answer may be helpful for others. Just create a jsp and add this code there

```
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil" %>
 <%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.NoSuchLayoutException" %>
 <%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutLocalServiceUtil" %>
 <%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.util.WebKeys" %>
 <%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.model.LayoutSet" %>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.model.User" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

 <%

User currentUser=null;

 try {
     currentUser = PortalUtil.getUser(request);
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 %>
```

Comment: It seems that your answer is not complete. I can't see a language specific switch...

Comment: idea was to get current user. Once I have got current user. language can be fetched from there. not an issue.